# Use NIO server with IO client

Tags: java, sockets, nio, apache-mina

I have server worked with **NIO** based on **Mina**.

I try to make **TCP/IP** client for this server using usual **java.net.Socket** technique. I can successfully establish connection (i.e. **org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandler.sessionOpened** invoked on server side after opening socket on client side). But if I try to write some bytes to socket (from client side) I have no any effect on server (i.e. **org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandler.messageReceived** doesn't invoked).

Could you please explain *why this is happen* and *is that possible to send some message to my NIO server from my usual client's Socket-based app*?

Comment: The TCP sent by as NIO or IO client or server is exactly the same and you can use either together in any combination because there is no different on the network.

Comment: Post some code. Probably you aren't flushing a ufferd stream at the client.

Comment: I have flushed it. I have completely worked IO client and completely worked NIO server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you installed your IoHandler in the acceptor ?

Comment: Yes, of course, the *org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor* is an acceptor for me. My NIO server absolutely correct works in production for a long time.